# Regular Expression to return a unknown string from within another string C#

Tags: regex, string, expression

Hi guys I have been battling with this for some time and am now giving up and hope you can help.

I have a string of indeterminate length, within that string there is a unknown character set that I need to return. The rules are:

- Upto 10 characters long min of 8
- The last 7 are always numeric
- The first 3 are alpha numeric
- The main string comes from a RTF file and starts on a new line so has a \n and always has a space after it

Thanks

Comment: You should definitely ask a coder to help you...

Comment: So you have a 8-10 characters long substring: `XXXXXXXX(XX)`. The first three are alphanumeric and the last seven numeric. Which of those are shortened, when the string is less than 10 characters long? Is it `AAANNNNNNN` or `ANNNNNNN` or something entirely different?

Answer (score 0):

I am writing this as an answer since I don't have enough reputation for commenting.

Based on the rules you provided, if the sub string is of 8 characters, then the first will be alpha numeric and the rest will be numeric.

A regex describing this and other all other possibilities might be:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9][0-9]{7,9}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}[0-9]{6,8}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}[0-9]{5,7}
```

Does this help, or did I not understand your question?

An example could help.